# Change NIC card speed duplex from 100M to 1Gb? Cannot connect remotely

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

Through remote desktop, I changed the speed duplex from 100Mbps to 1Gbps. Then after a few seconds of "processing" the change, my remote desktop connection ended. And now I can't connect to the server or its database.

Is there a reason why this would happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you messed up your network connection... which is the reason your connection dropped, and you can no longer connect over the now misconfigured network interface.  You'll need physical access to the machine, or the use of an out-of-band management system (ILO, iDRAC, VKM-over-IP, etc.) to correct your mistake.

Hopefully you've learned a valuable lesson about changing remote network connections you're relying on to connect over.